# SpeakAsync and multiple pronunciations for the same word

Tags: c#, .net, text-to-speech

I am using `SpeakAsync` successfully except when I hit words such as 'record'.

How does one flag the noun versus the verb so `SpeakAsync` outputs the correct pronunciations?

Is it possible to pass phonetic transcriptions to the `SpeechSynthesizer`?

The words are thrown at `SpeakAsync` in isolation, btw, not in phrases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can flag the word by adding it as a `Prompt` (typically through a `PromptBuilder`), rather than just sending a plain string to the synthesizer.

For example, you can specify the IPA pronunciation directly:

```
var pb = new PromptBuilder();
pb.AppendTextWithPronunciation("record", "ˈɹɛk.ɚd");
pb.AppendTextWithPronunciation("record", "ɹə.ˈkɔɹd");
synth.SpeakAsync(pb);
```

You can also add SSML directly with `AppendSsmlMarkup`.  You can see the full list of options here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.promptbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx

You can do a limited number of things with date and number formats using the `SayAs` hints, but there is not--as far as I'm aware--a way to give grammatical hints like "this is a noun" for single words.